# Recursive evaluation of prefixed expression in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, expression, prefix, evaluation

I am trying to write a recursive algorithm in C++ that evaluates an expression of the type: "operator" "variable" "variable" and returns the operation (example: input = + 3 4; output = 7). The operators are only the basic ones (+, -, *, /) and the variables are integers between 1 and 9. The problem is that I don't know how to start and what method to use. I can't use stacks or lists.

EDIT: I am studying for an exam of a introduction to C++ so I'm not allowed to use any complex method to solve the problem I only can use procedures, loops, recursivity and search and thread methods.

Thanks.

Comment: No need for recursion here, although you probably phrased the problem incorrectly.

Comment: I guess it's one of these "Implement X, but you can't use Y, Z, ..." exercises.

Comment: @Pubby with no (explicitly-declared) stack data structure, how is this possible without function recursion?

Comment: the recursion is need for more complex expressions such as "* - 2 8 + 3 4" which is equal to "(2-8)*(3+4)"

Answer (score 2):

Since you're (apparently) dealing only with binary operators, this is pretty trivial (with one caveat: although it won't use a stack explicitly, almost any sane implementation of recursion will use a stack implicitly).

The basic pattern looks something like this:

```
int apply(char op, int a, int b) {
    switch (op) { 
       case '+': return a + b;
       case '-': return a - b;
       case '/': return a / b;
       case '*': return a * b;
       default: throw bad_operator(op);
    }
}   

int expression(char *&input) {
    char op = *input++;

    if (isdigit(op)) 
       return op - '0';

    int a = expression(input);
    int b = expression(input);
    return apply(op, a, b);
}
```

Quick test program:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>

struct bad_operator : public std::logic_error { 
    bad_operator(char ch)  : 
        std::logic_error(std::string("Bad operator: ") + ch) 
    {}
};

int main() {
    char *input="+/42-43";
    std::cout << expression(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 but please s/operator/op/g ;)

Comment: that works but i can't use templates nor classes, thanks anyway

Comment: There are no templates nor classes in the previous example.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way. Pseudocode:

```
double Process(Parser & parser)
{
    Token token = parser.GetToken();

    if (token.Type == number)
        return (NumberToken)token.value;
    else if (token.Type == operator)
    {
        double left = Process(parser);
        double right = Process(parser);

        switch (OperatorToken)token.op:
        {
        case '+' :
            {
                return left + right;
            }
        // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This kind of problems is more easily solvable using stack, though.

Comment: can't use tokens, but thanks anyway

Comment: This is a pseudocode. Token may be a char, for instance. Depends on implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using recursion (no whitespace allowed in the expression):

```
#include <cstdio>

int eval(const char *s, const char **outptr)
{
    int a, b, y;
    const char *out;

    switch (*s) {
    case '+':
        a = eval(s + 1, &out);
        b = eval(out, &out);
        y = a + b;
        *outptr = out;
        break;
    case '-':
        a = eval(s + 1, &out);
        b = eval(out, &out);
        y = a - b;
        *outptr = out;
        break;
    case '*':
        a = eval(s + 1, &out);
        b = eval(out, &out);
        y = a * b;
        *outptr = out;
        break;
    case '/':
        a = eval(s + 1, &out);
        b = eval(out, &out);
        y = a / b;
        *outptr = out;
        break;
    default: /* '0'...'9'assumed */
        y = *s - '0';
        *outptr = s + 1;
        break;
    }

    return y;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *end;
    int x;

    x = eval(argv[1], &end);
    printf("%d\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
./eval +3+*45/62
26
```

Comment: you are giving away the answer to a homework question :)

Comment: @perreal I don't mind. :) I'm writing a parser right now, and I'm inside the topic pretty well :P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an input iterator (e.g., a pointer to the input string or a vector iterator), you can use something like this:

```
compute (input.iterator it) {
  if (it != input.end() and is_operator(*it)) {
     operator op = *it;
     int v1, v2;
     it++;
     v1 = is_operator(*it) ? compute(it) : *it;
     it++;
     v2 = is_operator(*it) ? compute(it) : *it;
     return operator_exec(op, v1, v2) 
  }
  return *it;
}
```

Comment: This solution will crash on expression with a single value, eg. 42.

Comment: i can't use that either, the froblem is focused on recursion

Comment: @Buradi, this is recursion though

Comment: i know i've updated my question becuase i didn't mention what mehtods I am allowed to use